# Queue doesn't work in production

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When I'm testing my website locally everything works. But in production, I get the following error: `Couldn't lease a task: API error 1 (taskqueue: UNKNOWN_QUEUE)`

I'm pretty sure my code is correct since it works locally. My best guess is that there is something wrong with the queue.yaml file, but it's dead simple:

```
queue:
- name: daemonQueue
  mode: pull
```

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:
Turns out enqueueing fails as well: `TickTask enqueue error: Failed to insert task: API error 1 (taskqueue: UNKNOWN_QUEUE)`
Here is how I'm enqueueing the task.

```
// Add the task to the queue.
func EnqueueWithName(c sessions.Context, task interface{}, tag string, name string) (err error) {
   buffer := new(bytes.Buffer) 
   err = gob.NewEncoder(buffer).Encode(task) 
   if err != nil { 
     return 
   } 
   newTask := &taskqueue.Task{ 
     Method:  "PULL", 
     Payload: buffer.Bytes(), 
     Tag:     tag, 
     Name:    name} 
   newTask, err = taskqueue.Add(c, newTask, "daemonQueue") 
   return err
 }
```

Comment: hmmmmm.... I remember I had an issue with pull queues where the url request for the "project ID". Sometimes it asks for the app id (ie "clever-blossom-273"), and sometimes it's the actual project number. I don't know which one you're using right now, but try the other one?

Comment: Patrice, were you pulling tasks from outside of GAE? In that case I think you need to provide a URL. But I'm doing things within GAE, so there is no place I need to provide the app id.

Comment: well it was within the App Engine, but I was calling it on the REST API, so yeah.... could've been done outside of the app engine

Comment: hmmm if you're not using the REST API, mind including your call?

Comment: I'm also having a conversation about this here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/fgxkrBFPQ-Q
David correctly pointed out that technically production isn't picking up my queue from queue.yaml, so that's probably the heart of the problem.

Comment: Yeah as he pointed out, you'll have trouble pulling from a queue with no tasks. I'm wondering how come the queue doesn't show up in your admin console though.... if you had that up it should all run perfectly....

Comment: If I was at a computer I'd check... but isn't there an appcfg command to ONLY push your queue.yaml?

Comment: Just checked from my cell (the bus ride is long). If you try appcfg.py update_ queues on your app folder. Does it do anything? (Technically deploying should do that... but worth testing)

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. (See the google groups thread.) Looks like you got the solution slightly earlier than David, so in that spirit, I'd be happy to accept your answer if you post it below.

Comment: As much as I appreciate the sentiment, David just answered here :) feel free to accept his answer :). I'm not here for the points. Just happy to have helped ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the queue configured in production. Make sure you are deploying your whole app directory so `queue.yaml` get uploaded. Point `goapp deploy` or `appcfg.py` at the directory holding `app.yaml` and `queue.yaml`, not at `app.yaml` directly.